# What is the difference between "context vector" and "word vector" in spaCy?

Tags: python, similarity, spacy, word-embedding

In the section about [vector similarity](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) it's noted that small models contain only context vectors and other models word vectors. I've been trying to find out how context vectors are trained/computed (also in general), but no such luck.

What are context vectors and how does their similarities compare to similarities between word vectors?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is entirely on topic here. It seems you are asking about computational linguistics concepts. Maybe take a look here: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/